# Update Red Hat Enterprise Linux's Packages Only To Specific Point Release

Tags: redhat, yum

Let's say that I have one RHEL6.2 64bit server running. Current latest version available is 6.4. Running "yum update" will update my server up to 6.4 straight away. What if I want to update only to certain point release?

For example, I want to update RHEL6.2 server only to RHEL6.3, not to 6.4. Any idea?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 5):

Use `subscription-manager` to [set the point release you want to lock your system to](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/preferred-os.html).

```
subscription-manager release --set=6.3
```

Comment: This does not work for RHEL 6.2.

Comment: Really? You should call Red Hat and attempt to get your money's worth out of those subscriptions you're overpaying for.

Comment: The command switch "release" does not exist in 6.2.

Comment: Ironically, you probably need to upgrade to the 6.3 version of subscription-manager.

Comment: In that case you might try using the fallback of setting the `--release` when you `register`. But you really should call Red Hat.

Comment: Red Hat says this does not work for EL6.2 systems, the example the OP is giving. There are a lot of 6.2 servers out there in production, bound by slow-moving applications like Oracle... With EL6.4 available, this is a fair question that doesn't seem to have a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed this new workaround in the redhat KB:

Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.2
Manually Setting a Preferred Operating System Release
Beginning in Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.3, Red Hat Subscription Manager could set a preferred operating system version to use to limit automatic updates for a system. This is covered in Section 5.7.4, “Setting Preferences for Systems”. However, it is not possible to set a preferred operating system through Red Hat Subscription Manager on older versions of Red Hat Enterprise Linux.

The system can be restricted to a certain operating system version on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.2 by editing the yum configuration. For example, to limit yum updates to 6.2-version packages:

```
[root@server ~]# echo 6.2 > /etc/yum/vars/releasever
```

Update: the above did not work for me on a new install of 6.2.

Comment: Did you try this?

Comment: Just now -- and it didn't work. I also tried on another 6.2 VM to update the subscription-manager package so that the --release option becomes available. The subscription manager package was updated, but then it's giving me an error that no releases are available (even though the subscription shows as active). Still haven't found a way to prevent my server from updating.

Comment: Right. I've seen this documented, but it does not work at all. So again, this is still a mystery :)

Comment: Yep very frustrating! The message I get if I update only subscription-manager on a stock 6.2 install is: 
[root@mgmt-vcd2 ~]# subscription-manager release --set=6.2 No releases match '6.2'. Consult 'release --list' for a full listing.

Comment: It will work for 6.3 and newer, but that doesn't help existing 6.2 installations.

Comment: I installed a fresh server just to try this: right after installing, I updated subscription manager (yum), did yum-config-manager --enable, and then run subscription-manager with the --release command set t to 6.2. Then I run yum update, and I noticed that I was upgraded to 6.4...

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, after using "yum update" you can use
"yum downgrade redhat-release"

Downgrade command will install the latest package before the last released. For example, if the latest is 6.4 it will downgrade to 6.3