# Updating RHEL 5.6 (without moving to ≥ 5.7)

Tags: redhat

I have a fresh install of RHEL 5.6 and I wanted to apply as many updates as possible without changing the main version to ≥ 5.7 (as I will be installing software on top of RHEL that requires 5.4-5.6). Is there a command that will allow me to achieve that?

Comment: I still don't know of a way to do this... However there are a few failed attempts at asking the same question. See [**here**](http://serverfault.com/questions/484841/update-red-hat-enterprise-linuxs-packages-only-to-specific-point-release) and [**here**](http://serverfault.com/questions/486076/keep-rhel-at-a-particular-minor-revision-level).

Comment: This appears to have worked for me so far: 

simply add the following @ /etc/yum.conf

`exclude=redhat-release-5Server*`